# Input string, output vowels and consonants to log, separately but in order

Tags: javascript, beginner, programming-challenge

I completed a short coding challenge and just want to know if I should use shorter methods of which I am unaware, or make it more readable.

```
 /*
 *
 * Complete the vowelsAndConsonants function.
 * Print your output using 'console.log()'.
 */
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
var strConsonants = "";
var strVowels = "";
var i;

for (i in s) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == "a" || s.charAt(i) == "e" || s.charAt(i) == "i" || 
s.charAt(i) == "o" || s.charAt(i) == "u") {
        strVowels += s.charAt(i);
    }
    else if (s.charAt(i) != "a" || s.charAt(i) != "e" || s.charAt(i) != "i" 
|| s.charAt(i) != "o" || s.charAt(i) != "u") {
        strConsonants += s.charAt(i);
    }
}

// console.log(strVowels);

i = 0;
for (i in strVowels) {
    console.log(strVowels.charAt(i));
}

// console.log(strConsonants);

i = 0;
for (i in strConsonants) {
     console.log(strConsonants.charAt(i));
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of providing you a "better" solution, I will try to give you some feedback the code.

---

## Block indentation

> ```
> function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
> var strConsonants = "";
> var strVowels = "";
> var i;
> // ..
> ```

To work with code it is important that it is formatted in a readable way. There are some style guides out there for example [from google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
  var strConsonants = "";
  var strVowels = "";
  var i;
  // ..
```

---

## [Type Embedded in Name](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/)

```
var strConsonants = "";
var strVowels = "";
```

In this variable names the type is embedded in the name

> Avoid placing types in method names; it's not only redundant, but it forces you to change the name if the type changes.

---

## [Array iteration and for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

For your task is the order important:

> Input string, output vowels and consonants to log, separately but in order

You can read [on MDN about the for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in),that it do not guaranties a traversal in order:

> **Note**: `for...in` should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important. [...]
>
> [...] iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore, it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.prototype.`forEach()` or the `for...of` loop) when iterating over arrays where the order of access is important.

---

## Make the Else-Statement Implicit

> ```
> if (s.charAt(i) == "a" || 
>     s.charAt(i) == "e" || 
>     s.charAt(i) == "i" || 
>     s.charAt(i) == "o" || 
>     s.charAt(i) == "u") {
>   strVowels += s.charAt(i);
> } else if (s.charAt(i) != "a" || 
>            s.charAt(i) != "e" || 
>            s.charAt(i) != "i" || 
>            s.charAt(i) != "o" || 
>            s.charAt(i) != "u") {
>   strConsonants += s.charAt(i);
> }
> ```

Currently the if-else statement tries to express: *If you are a, e, i, o, u do something, else if you are not from a, e, i, o, u do something*.

This is semanticly the same as: *If you are a, e, i, o, u do something, else do something*.

Additional we can wrap the condition of the `vowels` into its own method to make the code more readable.

```
function isVowel(letter) {
    return letter === "a" || 
           letter === "e" || 
           letter === "i" || 
           letter === "o" || 
           letter === "u"
}
```

The if-statement could now look like

```
var letter = s.charAt(i)
if (isVowel(letter)) {
  strVowels += letter;
} else {
  strConsonants += letter;
}
```

---

## String Concatenation..

> ```
> strVowels += letter
> ```
>
> Every time Strings get merged by `+` a new String gets created, because Strings are immutable, that means that for each concatenation new memory space gets allocated.

Better would be to use an array instead of a string an `push` into it.

```
vowels.push(letter)
```

---

## Example Refactoring

```
function isVowel(letter) {
    return letter === "a" ||
           letter === "e" ||
           letter === "i" ||
           letter === "o" ||
           letter === "u"
}

function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    var consonants = [];
    var vowels = [];

    for (var letter of s) {
        if (isVowel(letter)) {
            vowels.push(letter)
        } else {
            consonants.push(letter)
        }
    }

    for (var vowel of vowels) {
        console.log(vowel);
    }

    for (var constant of consonants) {
        console.log(constant);
    }
}
```

and from here you can still use some methods like `forEach` or using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to shorten an if-else

```
function isVowel(letter) {
    return letter === "a" ||
           letter === "e" ||
           letter === "i" ||
           letter === "o" ||
           letter === "u"
}

function print(x) {
    console.log(x)
}

function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    var consonants = [];
    var vowels = [];

    for (var letter of s) {
        isVowel(letter)
            ? vowels.push(letter)
            : consonants.push(letter)
    }

    vowels.forEach(print)
    consonants.forEach(print)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The shorter method can be achieved using Regex and it is also the fastest according to [JSBEN.CH](http://jsben.ch/):

```js
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";
var vowels = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
var consonants = str.match(/[^aeiou$]/gi);
    vowels.concat([''],consonants).forEach(function(k){
     console.log(k);
    });
```

According to comments from others, the code can be further improved as follow:

```
const str = "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog"; 
const vowels = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi); 
const consonants = str.match(/[^aeiou]/gi);   
vowels.concat([''],consonants).forEach(k => { console.log(k); } );
```

Comment: There's no reason to put the `$` into the character class of the regular expression. The indentation of the last 3 lines is a bit off, but apart from this: nice solution.

Comment: You could also use the `const` keyword for the variable declarations. And I think the callback function in the forEach method would be even a bit nicer like this `forEach( consonant => { console.log(consonant)})`